# Generated sql is trying to create a table when using entity framework dll with linqpad

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

Im trying to run a very simple ((from x in Addresses select x).Take(10)) query with my own entity framework dll and I get this exception.

SqlException
There is already an object named 'Contact' in the database

When I go to the sql generated code it is doing this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA SchemaName, TABLE_NAME Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact] (
    [OwnerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OwnerIdDsc] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StateCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [trad_lregionidName] [nvarchar](100),
    [et_lastbouncesendidName] [nvarchar](100),
    [TransactionCurrencyIdName] [nvarchar](100),
    [PreferredSystemUserIdName] [nvarchar](160),
    [trad_lbrandidName] [nvarchar](100),
    [CreatedOnBehalfByName] [nvarchar](160),
    [CreatedByYomiName] [nvarchar](160),
    [trad_lcampaignidName] [nvarchar](128),
    [trad_lcompanyreportingidName] [nvarchar](100),
    [trad_lrelationshipmgridName] [nvarchar](160),
    [MasterContactIdYomiName] [nvarchar](450),
    [PreferredEquipmentIdName] [nvarchar](160),
    [trad_laccount1accounttype1idName] [nvarchar](100),
    [PreferredSystemUserIdYomiName] [nvarchar](160),
    [MasterContactIdName] [nvarchar](160),
    [trad_lrelationshipmgridYomiName] [nvarchar](160),
    [OriginatingLeadIdYomiName] [nvarchar](450),
    [ModifiedByName] [nvarchar](160),
    [ModifiedOnBehalfByName] [nvarchar](160),
    [CreatedOnBehalfByYomiName] [nvarchar](160),
    [ModifiedOnBehalfByYomiName] [nvarchar](160), ... goes on
```

...

Any ideas on why is this trying to create a table?

Comment: Can you run this code without issue outside of `LinqPad` e.g. in a test C# program?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EntityFramework, but I'm guessing that __MigrationHistory contains details of changes to your database schema and it must think that your database is out-of-date and needs this table added. This is more likely to be an Entity-Framework issue than a LinqPad issue, so I have tagged it as such and hopefully someone will be able to help you resolve this.

Comment: When I query using this dll and a c# program it works just fine. The way I configured it is using the default constructor and an xml connection string value. The right table entities come up in the object  explorer of linqpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and this post fixed the problem for me : http://jameschambers.com/2014/02/changing-the-namespace-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-first-databases/

basically, it's a problem of namespace change of your EF migration conf class between migrations : the table __MigrationHistory keeps a reference to your old namespace.